# M:N relation an query

Tags: mysql, sql

i've some problems with a specific mysql query an an specific construct.
There are 2 tables:

```
table users (id, username)
table groups (id, groupname)
```

these 2 tables are in an m:n relation, but there are 2 tables  for that.

First in maps user to groups

```
table usertogroups (idmaster, idslave)
```

where idmaster is related to users.id and idslave is related groups.id

Second maps groups to users

```
table groupstouser (idmaster, idslave)
```

where idmaster is related to groups.id an idslave is related to users.id

Depend on the application it could not be changed.

Now i want to get all groups with the depending users in one query with the relation of both table, groupstouser and usertogroups.
I've tried al lot of statements, but if I take the second table in it doesn't work.

Any helpfull Ideas?

Comment: You have to get rid of one of these two association tables. Logically, each is a mirror image of the other. It's redundant, useless, and it could be a source of errors if the tables are not kept in perfect sync.

Comment: Two remarks: (1) "Depend on the application *it could not be changed*." It could not be changed *at this time* maybe. But you should definitively push to phase-out that stupidity. *Relations* are not *pointers*. They are bidirectional by nature. Whoever came to this "solution" might have either no understanding of *relational* databases -- or there is definitively some subtleties here that is not obvious at first sight? (2) "I've tried al lot of statements, but [...] it doesn't work" could you show some of your statements? Once again "at first sight" this is just a `JOIN`...

Comment: @MarkoKohn Rather than changing the title to `[SOLVED]`, please mark the accepted answer using the large tick mark to the left of the answer. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this as an inline view to get the data from both association tables :

```
((SELECT idmaster AS userid, idslave AS groupid FROM userstogroup)
UNION
(SELECT idslave AS userid, idmaster AS groupid FROM groupstouser)) all_associations
```

Then you can query like this :

```
SELECT groups.groupname, users.username
FROM groups
INNER JOIN ((SELECT idmaster AS userid, idslave AS groupid FROM userstogroup)
            UNION
           (SELECT idslave AS userid, idmaster AS groupid FROM groupstouser)) all_associations
ON groups.id =  all_associations.groupid
INNER JOIN users
ON users.id =  all_associations.userid
```

And here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/747f4/4).

Comment: Thnaks Miklos, it works great. In my tests the problem was the creation on the inline view. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, it might solve your problem:

```
(SELECT * FROM usertogroups  WHERE idmaster=10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM groupstouser  WHERE idslave=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your database design is wrong.

When a `user` is assigned to a `group` only single table can be used for it. You must be saving duplicate records in both `usertogroups` and `groupstouser`.

Try to get your data from only single table.

```
SELECT * FROM usertogroups order by idslave
```

If I am wrong that you are not saving duplicate data in both the tables, then specify reason of having two tables

Comment: No, i did not save duplicate data. The design of the application is fixed, so i use there data and try to generate a report.

Comment: @MarcoKohn "No, I did not save duplicate data." you should definitively explain in your question why `usertogroups` and `groupstouser` are different. Perhaps by showing an example of actual data. It is very perturbing -- and might lead to sub-optimal answers to your problem.